# Define variable according to selected tab and pass it through js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to programming and I'm develloping a website with NodeJS that has a form that should be stored in a database. That is already done. But one of the variables that should be stored is dependent on which tab the user selected in the form. I think I already managed to at least make a variable defined according to the selected tab.
The problem is that I need to pass that variable from the javascript file linked to the html to the js file that has the variables that are going to be stored in the database.
So far I have this:

**FORM.JS**

```
var structName = true;

function structureTypeDefiner(tab) {
  structName = tab.id;
};

module.exports = structName;
```

**AUTH.JS**

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const winax = require('winax');
let formJs = require('../public/js/form.js');

const form = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.FORM_HOST, /*ip address of the server, when not running locally*/
    user: process.env.FORM_USER,
    password: process.env.FORM_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.FORM
});

(...)

exports.sendForm = (req, res) => {
    //console.log(req.body);

    const { name, length, spacing, structureType, H, h, R, b1, B, b3, b4, t1, t2, t3, openN, openS, openE, openW, Lr, Lf } = req.body;

    structureType = structName;

    form.query('INSERT INTO form SET ?', {Name: name, Length: length, Spacing: spacing, StructureType: structureType, NorthColumnHeigth:H, SouthColumnHeigth:h, RidgeHeigth:R, RidgeDistance:b1, Width:B, CantileverLength:b3, CentralColumnDistance:b4, NorthBracingLength:t1, CentralBracingLeftLength:t2, CentralBracingRightLength:t3, OpenFaçadeNorth:openN, OpenFaçadeSouth:openS, OpenFaçadeEast: openE, OpenFaçadeWest:openW,   RoofPurlinsSpacing: Lr, FaçadePurlinsSpacing: Lf}, (error, results) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(results);
            generateStructure()
            return res.render('addStudy', {
                //message: 'User registered.'
                
            });
        };
    });
};
```

I get the error "ReferenceError: document is not defined". Does someone know how to overcome this?

Thanks in advance for any help!
Ana

EDIT:
Now that the passing of the variable is ok with putting that part of the code in a diferent file, I arranged the code in order to make it save in the DB. But I get the error: "ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'StructureType' cannot be null!

**AUXILIAR.JS**

```
let structName;

function structureTypeDefiner(tab) {
  structName = tab.id;
  alert(structName);
  module.exports =  structName;
};
```

**AUTH.JS**

```
exports.sendForm = (req, res) => {
    //console.log(req.body);

    const { name, length, spacing, H, h, R, b1, B, b3, b4, t1, t2, t3, openN, openS, openE, openW, Lr, Lf } = req.body;

    //let structureType = formJs.structName;

    form.query('INSERT INTO form SET ?', {Name: name, Length: length, Spacing: spacing, StructureType: formJs.structName, NorthColumnHeigth:H, SouthColumnHeigth:h, RidgeHeigth:R, RidgeDistance:b1, Width:B, CantileverLength:b3, CentralColumnDistance:b4, NorthBracingLength:t1, CentralBracingLeftLength:t2, CentralBracingRightLength:t3, OpenFaçadeNorth:openN, OpenFaçadeSouth:openS, OpenFaçadeEast: openE, OpenFaçadeWest:openW,   RoofPurlinsSpacing: Lr, FaçadePurlinsSpacing: Lf}, (error, results) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(results);
            generateStructure()
            return res.render('addStudy', {
                //message: 'User registered.'
                
            });
        };
    });
};
```

Comment: Where in your code are you referencing "document"?
If you're doing this on the server side, then the error is expected, as "document" is normally a browser global variable.

Comment: @Dozatron I'm only calling document in the form.js (just put a fraction on it on the post, sorry) for other purposes of the form

Comment: Should I make another js file purposefully for this case and when I call it into the server side there's no problem?

Comment: Basically, get all the data from the "document" on client side and then pass it on to the backend. Your Form.js runs in Node, which doesn't know what "document" is.

Comment: Do not import "../public/js/form.js" in Node, as it's supposed to run in the browser.

Comment: When you make a HTTP request to your server from the browser, add a new property "tabId" to the body of the request, along with "name", "length", "spacing", etc... Then you can read that property in your "sendForm" handler function and take any necessary action.

Comment: @Dozatron solved the problem by using a new js file, but now I get this "ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'StructureType' cannot be null" it seems is not being passed into the AUTH.JS. Any thoughts?

Comment: your `structureType` seems to be null
can you check that you're passing it in correctly in the request body?

Comment: @Dozatron I updated the post with the code after the first problem is solved. Theres some problem when passing the variable, it gets do auth.js as null

Comment: First, you have the declaration of `structureType` commented out. You probably want to uncomment that.
Next, `formJs` will be undefined. Where is it supposed to come from? From `req.body`?